# How can I read the message that someone replied to in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, reply

I am new to making discord bots with Discord.py
Is there any way to get the message characters of a message that someone replied to?
As in, read the message that someone replied to; not the actual message of the reply.

[image: Read what's in the red box after replying]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can.
For this, you'll have to use Message.reference to get the `discord.Message` object of the message you replied to.

In this case, you would have to use
`ctx.message.reference` which returns a `discord.MessageReference` object.

using the `message_id` attribute you can get the id from the message you replied to.

You would have to use
`await ctx.channel.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)`
to get a full `discord.Message` object, which has attribute `content`

Full code would look like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
    await ctx.send(message.content)
```

Here's the result:
[image]